# How to pass variable as parameter in ajax call

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-dialog

I have a click function which call jQuery dialogue modal poup. I want URL.Action to be call inside the dialog's open function which needs to pass parameters.  But I need to pass the data parameter (variable) dynamically.
How do I pass this dynamically?  How do I store it in a variable and pass it to the "data:" field? I couldn't get it to work with following code.

> Note: Also from the syntax, -- url = '@(Html.Raw(Url.Action("ShowPopUp", "Home", new { serviceID = svc, serviceMasterId = masterId, serviceStatusId = statusId }))) > showing the following warning messages
>    1. The name 'svc' does not exist in the current context
>    2. The name 'masterId' does not exist in the current context
>    3. The name 'statusId' does not exist in the current context

```
    $('.lnkRequest').click(function () {
        serviceId = $(this).attr('serviceID');
        $('#dialog').css("display", "block");
        $('#dialog').data('svcId', $(this).attr('serviceID'));
        $('#dialog').data('svcMasterId', $(this).attr('serviceMasterID'));
        $('#dialog').data('svcStatusId', $(this).attr('serviceStatusID'));
        $('#dialog').dialog('open');
        return false;
    });

    $('#dialog').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        height: 'auto',
        width: 'auto',
        draggable: false,
        open: function (event, ui) {
            var svc = $(this).data('svcId');
            var masterId = $(this).data('svcMasterId');
            var statusId = $(this).data('svcStatusId');
            url = '@(Html.Raw(Url.Action("ShowPopUp", "Home", new { serviceID = svc, serviceMasterId = masterId, serviceStatusId = statusId })))',                                  
            $(this).load(url);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery's `load` method accepts a `data` parameter.

```
$('#dialog').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        height: 'auto',
        width: 'auto',
        draggable: false,
        open: function (event, ui) {
            var svc = $(this).data('svcId');
            var masterId = $(this).data('svcMasterId');
            var statusId = $(this).data('svcStatusId');
            url = '@(Html.Raw(Url.Action("ShowPopUp", "Home")))';                                 
            $(this).load(url, 
                {
                    serviceId: svc,
                    serviceMasterId: masterId,
                    serviceStatusId: statusId
                });
        }
    });
```

Source: http://api.jquery.com/load/

See the very last example on the page.

Answer (score 0):

get the dialog id using jquery and then load

pls follow links:

[MVC 2 - Display a jquery dialog that contains a partial view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8568248/mvc-2-display-a-jquery-dialog-that-contains-a-partial-view)

[also this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14981485/open-jquery-dialog-with-a-parameter)